# How can I set PHP 8.1 in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I wanted to change PHP version in PhpStorm to 8.1 but only 8.0 is available in settings. How can I solve this?

I've tried to synchronize it with `composer.json` (there is 8.1) but it did not help.

Comment: 1) What is your PhpStorm version? 2) by "set PHP 8.1" do you mean the PHP Language Level (so the IDE allows to use PHP 8.1 specific features etc) or PHP Interpreter?

Comment: 1) 2022.2.3, i've updated it today 2) yes, i want to change the PHP Language Level

Comment: Please show a screenshot where you cannot change the PHP Language Level to 8.1 (you can upload it to any pic/file sharing service and post a link if you cannot post an actual picture). It may show some nuances that otherwise are ignored. Because PhpStorm 2022.2.3 allows setting 8.1 as a PHP Language Level.

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/b9f9c481fee5534be3f5d1097861b7b6

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you have 2022.2 version? Please check/show your `Help | About`. PHP 8.1 is present here: https://i.imgur.com/X2ujQs9.png 2) What will you see if you disable `Settings | PHP | Composer | Synchronize IDE settings with composer.json` ? 3) What option do you see if you try to change the Language level via Status bar?

Comment: The screenshot shows the availables of the installed PHP. When the project is open, you can select it from the bottom statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

In settings > PHP; There is the PHP Language level and CLI Interpreter.
If it is not showing maybe you can update PhpStorm,

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?